# Is there something similar to scp for tunneling over RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, scp

Similar to how you can scp over ssh, is there something similar for over rdp?

I'm currently using the \tsclient\ (i.e. mapped drives) when on the remote server. But I wondering if there is a way of doing something similar triggered from the client (similar to how SCP works?).

I realise I could install FTP, WebDav etc, but just wondering if there is a built in tool.

Comment: i'm perhaps not understanding your question 'cos it has been a while with these tools. but why not map drive and share it, within RDP? You mention FTP so surely mapping a drive is as good?  unless perhaps.. is it encryption you want? or command line?

Comment: He is looking for a built in tool that can do a client side push of data, instead of a server side pull of the data.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no client initiated copy functionality without using 3rd party tools other than what the clipboard can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can share your local drive(s) over rdp and they will show up as network mapped shares on the remote side. You can copy on the remote side into/from them.

EDIT: Misunderstood the original question. The above is what the questioner currently uses.

Comment: That is the `\\tsclient` solution he said he is already currently doing, and he was asking if there was a solution other than that.

Comment: Thanks Bgs, Scott is right that's the tsclient solution - I've updated my question with more detail.

Comment: I see. The \tsclient\ wasn't obvious to me. Now it's clear. Now I agree with Scott as well... :)